# Bandipur national park opening dates?

Tags: online-resources, india, planning, national-parks

I am trying to find opening dates for bandipur park in India. I have not been able to find them, does anyone here know?

Is there also a Web page where one can book safaris in the park?

Answer (score 2):

Bandpur National park in Karnataka India is open round the year. To get details on resorts attached to it, to book a safari and other such details check out blogs on wildtrails of India and it should give complete details. If you need any specific details, post here and I will respond.

Manjunath M Gowda

Comment: Hi @Manjunath and welcome to travel.SE! This site is in Q&A format, so you should provide as much specific answer as you can. This is different from classic forums approach, so please update your answer.

Comment: Thanks - could you include a link to a site with information about safaris?

Answer (score 1):

The Bandipur National Park does have an [official website](http://www.bandipurtigerreserve.in/).

It is open round the year. The packages and tariffs for various activities and safaris are included [here](http://www.bandipurtigerreserve.in/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7&Itemid=44).